# How can i create a responsive menu on html css and jquery,that hide li element one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example this is menu :

```
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

I need to hide the 6 on resize, after that 5, and the menu will look like that:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>1
    <ul>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to take the 6,5 elements and have them in a dropdown under 1?

Comment: Yes, on lower resolution.

Comment: You can [bind to window resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) and then do whatever you want with the html in the callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course make it more efficient. This is just illustrating the solution.

**Your HTML:**

```
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    var liWidth = 100;
    if($(window).height()/$('.main-menu').children().length < liWidth){
        console.log('here');
        if($('.main-menu li').first().find('ul').length > 0){
            $('.main-menu li').first().find('ul').append('<li>'+$('.main-menu li').last().html()+'</li>');
            $('.main-menu li').last().remove();
        }
        else{
            $('.main-menu li').first().append('<ul><li>'+$('.main-menu li').last().html()+'</li></ul>');
            $('.main-menu li').last().remove();
        }
    }

    else if($(window).height()/($('.main-menu').children().length + 1) > liWidth){
        console.log('there');
        if($('.main-menu li').first().find('ul li').length === 1 ){
            $('.main-menu').append('<li>' +$('.main-menu li').first().find('ul li').html() + '</li>')
            $('.main-menu li').first().find('ul').remove();
        }
        else if ($('.main-menu li').first().find('ul li').length > 1) {
            $('.main-menu').append('<li>' +$('.main-menu li').first().find('ul li').last().html() + '</li>')
            $('.main-menu li').first().find('ul li').last().remove();
        }
    } 
});
```

**Outcome:**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/razvangl/3aWqk/)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you mean, here is how i will do it. 
I will build my html with the sub menu and hide it with css.  and use the resize() to 
hide or unhide the element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you only need CSS and media queries ( as you wish )

**HTML**

```
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li>1
      <ul id="nav2">
       <li>6</li>
       <li>5</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li id="five" >5</li>
    <li id="six" >6</li>
 </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav2 li {
   display:none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 580px)
 {
#nav2 li {
    display:block;
}
#five,#six {
    display:none;
}

}
```